# Laravel Notification with ShouldQueue: toDatabase store different [data]

Tags: laravel, notifications, queue, laravel-5.6

I have **ServiceOrderCreated.php** notification and want to use ShouldQueue, but it stores notification other than when I don't use ShouldQueue.

These are data sent to ServiceOrderCreated Class:

```
//notification
class ServiceOrderCreated extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable;

protected $serviceOrder;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(ServiceOrder $serviceOrder)
{
    $this->serviceOrder = $serviceOrder;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail',  'database'];
}


/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return json
 */
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    //dd($this->serviceOrder);
    return [
        $this->serviceOrder
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $message = new MailMessage;
    $message->subject('Sportservis-Hostivice: Nová zákazka č. '.$this->serviceOrder->id);
    foreach ($this->serviceOrder->serviceOrderItem as $item) {
        $message->line('<li>'.$item->customerOrderAsset->name.' - '.$item->serviceType->name.' - '.$item->price.'</li>');
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Problem is, that when I remove "implements ShouldQueue", it stores whole collection (`$newServiceOrder`) to Notifications table ([data] column). When "implements ShouldQueue" is in place, only bare model without relations is stored to Notifications table.

Any idea? Did I miss Something?

**UPDATE**

This is the collection which is passed from **ServiceOrderController.php** to notification.

```
$newServiceOrder = ServiceOrder::with(['serviceOrderItem', 'serviceOrderItem.serviceType', 'serviceOrderItem.customerOrderAsset', 'customer'])->find($serviceOrder->id)
$newServiceOrder->customer->notify(new ServiceOrderCreated($newServiceOrder));
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is what is store in notifications table when I **don't** use **ShouldQueue**:
https://pastebin.com/hXF03tEa

And this is what is stored when I use **ShouldQueue**:
https://pastebin.com/Vb6hFZkH

Comment: What Laravel version is this? And your problem *seems* to be a feature, it re-fetches the model when job is being executed.

Comment: Hi, it is laravel 5.6. Well, when I dd()  data within toDatabase() method, it renders whole collection.

Comment: What do you mean by **only bare model without relations**, nothing is loaded? - like doing `new Model();`. Anyway, I think I understand what you are trying to say, so how do you invoke this notification, show controller code. `toMail(..)` works as expected?

Comment: @Kyslik I have updated the question. By bare model I mean only ServiceOrder without any relations. When ShouldQueue is not used, everything is fine.

Comment: Try returning this `return $this->serviceOrder->toArray();`

Comment: @Kyslik Still the same. Just to be clear, when i use ShouldQueue, stored notification in DB is: https://pastebin.com/Vb6hFZkH
When i dont use ShouldQueue, stored notification is this: https://pastebin.com/hXF03tEa - just to show what I mean.